# How to display a popup on mouse hover of an HTML element in the WebBrowser control of a Form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the following code, C# and js are linked together and ToolStripDropDown is used to create a popup, but the mouseleave event of js does not fire when the mouse leaves the HTML element.

However, when I move the mouse over the popup, the mouseleave event fires.
If you move the mouse away from other directions, the mouseleave event will not fire.

[image]

Also, it seems to fire when the popup is not shown on the C# side.
I tried writing a code to focus on the WebBrowser control after Show, but even so, mouseleave of js doesn't fire.
I wonder why this is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ToolStripDropDown toolStripDropDown;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            toolStripDropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
            toolStripDropDown.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            toolStripDropDown.Padding = Padding.Empty;
            toolStripDropDown.DropShadowEnabled = false;

            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new TestClasss(this);
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<script>
                window.onload = function() {
                    var elm = document.createElement('div');
                    elm.innerHTML = 'test';
                    document.body.appendChild(elm);

                    elm.onmouseover = function() {
                        window.external.ShowPopup(this.getBoundingClientRect().left, this.getBoundingClientRect().top);
                    };

                    elm.onmouseleave = function()
                    {
                        window.external.ClosePopup();
                    };
                };
            </script>";
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class TestClasss
    {
        private Form1 viewer;

        public TestClasss(Form1 viewer)
        {
            this.viewer = viewer;
        }

        public void ShowPopup(int x, int y)
        {
            var panel1 = new Panel();
            panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;

            var label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = "popup";
            panel1.Controls.Add(label1);

            var toolStripControlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(panel1);
            toolStripControlHost.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            toolStripControlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty;

            viewer.toolStripDropDown.Items.Clear();
            viewer.toolStripDropDown.Items.Add(toolStripControlHost);
            viewer.toolStripDropDown.Show(viewer.webBrowser1, new Point(x, y), ToolStripDropDownDirection.AboveRight);
        }

        public void ClosePopup()
        {
            viewer.toolStripDropDown.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Using System;

Using System.Collections.Generic;

Using System.ComponentModel;

Using System.Data;

Using System.Drawing;

Using System.Text;

Using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1

{

```
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.MouseOver += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Body_MouseOver);
    }

    void Body_MouseOver(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ToElement != null && e.ToElement.TagName == "H1" && e.ToElement.GetAttribute("processed") != "true")
        {
            string[] words = e.ToElement.InnerHtml.Split(' ');
            e.ToElement.InnerHtml = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
                e.ToElement.InnerHtml += "<span> " + words[i] + " </span>";

            foreach (HtmlElement el in e.ToElement.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
                el.MouseOver += new HtmlElementEventHandler(e_MouseOver);

            e.ToElement.SetAttribute("processed", "true");
        }
    }

    void e_MouseOver(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripTextBox1.Text = e.ToElement.InnerText;
    }


}
```